# How to read and process multiple JSON API responses asynchronously?

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, webclient

I'm reading JSON responses from the Binance Api, from [this link](https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=DOGEEUR)

I need to get some of the data out of it and this is the code I'm using:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Form1
    Private wc As New WebClient()
    Private wc1 As New WebClient()
    Private wc2 As New WebClient()
    Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim btc = Await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCEUR")
        Dim doge = Await wc1.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=DOGEEUR")
        Dim bnb = Await wc2.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBEUR")

        Dim d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(btc)
        Dim d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(doge)
        Dim d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(bnb)

        Label1.Text = "PRICE " + d("lastPrice")
        Label2.Text = "24H CHANGE " + d("priceChange")
        Label3.Text = "24H CHANGE % " + d("priceChangePercent")
        Label4.Text = "HIGH 24H " + d("highPrice")
        Label5.Text = "LOW 24H " + d("lowPrice")
        Label6.Text = "PRICE " + d1("lastPrice")
        Label7.Text = "24H CHANGE " + d1("priceChange")
        Label8.Text = "24H CHANGE % " + d1("priceChangePercent")
        Label9.Text = "HIGH 24H " + d1("highPrice")
        Label10.Text = "LOW 24H " + d1("lowPrice")
        Label11.Text = "PRICE " + d2("lastPrice")
        Label12.Text = "24H CHANGE " + d2("priceChange")
        Label13.Text = "24H CHANGE % " + d2("priceChangePercent")
        Label14.Text = "HIGH 24H " + d2("highPrice")
        Label15.Text = "LOW 24H " + d2("lowPrice")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
End Class
```

This code is working perfectly, the `Timer.Intrval` is set at 1000ms, but after a while I'm getting an exception:

> System.NotSupportedException: WebClient does not support concurrent I/O operations

in the line:

```
Dim bnb = Await wc2.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBEUR")
```

How can I solve it? It doesn't seems wrong cause I'm using 3 different WebClients objects to do that.

Also, how can I just display just 2 decimals after the comma ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have all async method to call, I suggest to move the API requests to an async method that, when initialized, keeps sending requests to the API - with a delay between calls - until the [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken) passed to the method signals that its time to quit.
I'm passing a [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) delegate to the method, which is responsible to update the UI when the Tasks started by the aysnc method return their results.

The delegate of course executes in the UI Thread (here; anyway, the Thread that created and initialized it).

You can run this method from any other method / event handler that can be aysnc. Here, for example, the `Click` handler of a button. You can also start it from the `Form.Load` handler. Or whatever else.

I've decide to deserialize the JSON responses to a class model, since some values need to be converted to different types to make sense. As the Date/Time values returned, which are expressed in Unix (milliseconds) notation. So I'm using a custom `UnixDateTimeConverter` to convert the Date/Time values to `DateTimeOffset` structures.

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Converters

Private ctsBinance As CancellationTokenSource = Nothing

Private Async Sub SomeButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SomeButton.Click
    ctsBinance = New CancellationTokenSource()

    Dim progressReport = New Progress(Of BinanceResponseRoot())(AddressOf BinanceProgress)
    Try
        ' Pass the Pogress<T> delegate, the delay in ms and the CancellationToken
        Await DownLoadBinanceData(progressReport, 1000, ctsBinance.Token)
    Catch tcEx As TaskCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine("Tasks canceled")
    Finally
        ctsBinance.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub BinanceProgress(results As BinanceResponseRoot())
    Console.WriteLine("PRICE " & results(0).LastPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("24H CHANGE " & results(0).PriceChange.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("24H CHANGE % " & results(0).PriceChangePercent.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("HIGH 24H " & results(0).HighPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("LOW 24H " & results(0).LowPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("PRICE " & results(1).LastPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("24H CHANGE " & results(1).PriceChange.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("24H CHANGE % " & results(1).PriceChangePercent.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("HIGH 24H " & results(1).HighPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("LOW 24H " & results(1).LowPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("PRICE " & results(1).LastPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("24H CHANGE " & results(2).PriceChange.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("24H CHANGE % " & results(2).PriceChangePercent.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("HIGH 24H " & results(2).HighPrice.ToString("N2"))
    Console.WriteLine("LOW 24H " & results(2).LowPrice.ToString("N2"))
End Sub
```

To cancel the execution of the Tasks, call the `Cancel()` method of the `CancellationTokenSource`. If the Tasks are not canceled before the Form / Window closes, call it when the Form / Window is closing, handling that event.

```
 ctsBinance?.Cancel()
 ctsBinance = Nothing
```

**The worker method**:

The method keeps running queries to the API in parallel until a cancellation is requested, calling the [Cancel()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.cancel) method of the [CancellationTokenSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource).

I'm using a static [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) to send the API requests, since this is more likely its kind of job (no custom initialization, it uses all defaults: you may need to initialize a HttpClientHandler in some contexts, as specific Security Protocols).
All [HttpClient.GetAsStringAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync) Tasks are added to a `List(Of Task)`, then all Tasks are executed calling [Task.WhenAll()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall).

When all Tasks return, the API responses are deserialized to the `BinanceResponseRoot` model and the `Progress<T>` delegate is called to update the UI with the information received.

```
Private Shared binanceClient As New HttpClient()

Public Async Function DownLoadBinanceData(progress As IProgress(Of BinanceResponseRoot()), 
    delay As Integer, token As CancellationToken) As Task

    While Not token.IsCancellationRequested
        Dim tasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))({
            binanceClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCEUR"),
            binanceClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=DOGEEUR"),
            binanceClient.GetStringAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBEUR")
        })

        Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

        Dim btcEur = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BinanceResponseRoot)(tasks(0).Result)
        Dim dogeEur = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BinanceResponseRoot)(tasks(1).Result)
        Dim bnbEur = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BinanceResponseRoot)(tasks(2).Result)

        progress.Report({btcEur, dogeEur, bnbEur})

        Await Task.Delay(delay, token)
    End While
End Function
```

**Class Model to convert that JSON data to the corresponding .Net Type values**:

```
Public Class BinanceResponseRoot
    Public Property Symbol As String
    Public Property PriceChange As Decimal
    Public Property PriceChangePercent As Decimal
    Public Property WeightedAvgPrice As Decimal
    Public Property PrevClosePrice As Decimal
    Public Property LastPrice As Decimal
    Public Property LastQty As Decimal
    Public Property BidPrice As Decimal
    Public Property BidQty As Decimal
    Public Property AskPrice As Decimal
    Public Property AskQty As Decimal
    Public Property OpenPrice As Decimal
    Public Property HighPrice As Decimal
    Public Property LowPrice As Decimal
    Public Property Volume As Decimal
    Public Property QuoteVolume As Decimal
    <JsonConverter(GetType(BinanceDateConverter))>
    Public Property OpenTime As DateTimeOffset
    <JsonConverter(GetType(BinanceDateConverter))>
    Public Property CloseTime As DateTimeOffset
    Public Property FirstId As Long
    Public Property LastId As Long
    Public Property Count As Long
End Class

Friend Class BinanceDateConverter
    Inherits UnixDateTimeConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(t As Type) As Boolean
        Return t = GetType(Long) OrElse t = GetType(Long?)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, t As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Dim uxDT As Long? = serializer.Deserialize(Of Long?)(reader)
        Return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(uxDT.Value)
    End Function
    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)
        Dim dtmo = DirectCast(value, DateTimeOffset)
        If dtmo <> DateTimeOffset.MinValue Then
            serializer.Serialize(writer, CType(DirectCast(value, DateTimeOffset).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds(), ULong))
        Else
            MyBase.WriteJson(writer, Nothing, serializer)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Big thanks Jimi! I'm quite speachless everytime you put yourself into answer my questions. I didn't expected you used also a cancellation token which shows your professionality. It requires me some time to fully understand it and make it work before into my mind and then into the compiler, but thanks to your descriptions it will be easier to understand also to anyone that will have my same problem. That deserves a bounty. Thanks, Mattia !

Comment: Well, thanks :) I ditched the Tablet (I cannot use that thing to write code), so this is tested. It's also meant to be just copy/pasted. You're using WinForms, so to test this just paste the code inside a Form, add a button to initialize the async procedure and run it. You'll see the results appear in the Output pane. Add another Button to cancel the Tasks at any time. See the notes about it. You could also use a DataGridView to present the data.

Answer (score 0):

1000ms is probably too fast, the `wc2.DownloadStringTaskAsync` task is probably not finished. You can [Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.stop?view=net-5.0) your timer before starting those download tasks and [Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.start?view=net-5.0) it again when the tasks are done:

```
Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Timer1.Stop

    Dim downloadTasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))

    Dim btc = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCEUR")
    Dim doge = wc1.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=DOGEEUR")
    Dim bnb = wc2.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BNBEUR")

    downloadTasks.Add(btc)
    downloadTasks.Add(doge)
    downloadTasks.Add(bnb)

    Await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)

    Dim d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(btc.Result)
    Dim d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(doge.Result)
    Dim d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(bnb.Result)

    Label1.Text = "PRICE " + d("lastPrice")
    Label2.Text = "24H CHANGE " + d("priceChange")
    Label3.Text = "24H CHANGE % " + d("priceChangePercent")
    Label4.Text = "HIGH 24H " + d("highPrice")
    Label5.Text = "LOW 24H " + d("lowPrice")
    Label6.Text = "PRICE " + d1("lastPrice")
    Label7.Text = "24H CHANGE " + d1("priceChange")
    Label8.Text = "24H CHANGE % " + d1("priceChangePercent")
    Label9.Text = "HIGH 24H " + d1("highPrice")
    Label10.Text = "LOW 24H " + d1("lowPrice")
    Label11.Text = "PRICE " + d2("lastPrice")
    Label12.Text = "24H CHANGE " + d2("priceChange")
    Label13.Text = "24H CHANGE % " + d2("priceChangePercent")
    Label14.Text = "HIGH 24H " + d2("highPrice")
    Label15.Text = "LOW 24H " + d2("lowPrice")

    Timer1.Start

End Sub
```

That way you will be sure the previous download has completed.

You can also check if the WebClient is still busy using the [WebClient.IsBusy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.isbusy?view=net-5.0) property before starting another download.

As far as displaying 2 decimals, take a look at [Strings.FormatNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatnumber?view=net-5.0). You can specify a `NumDigitsAfterDecimal` parameter that indicates

> how many places are displayed to the right of the decimal. The default value is -1, which indicates that the computer's regional settings are used.

Comment: Well yes, stopping the timer right before and start it again at the end would solve it. Endeed it does, but since I'm using an async method, Id like to keep going with that. Thanks

Comment: Using an Async method makes no difference in this case. Since you are awaiting each download task, it's going to execute them one after the other. You want to create a list of tasks for all 3 and place your await there. That way all 3 downloads run at the same time.

Comment: I'm getting 3 errors, all 3 in downloadtask.add as I Cant convert strings in task

Comment: Change list to `New List(Of Task(Of String))`

Comment: error: Impossible to convert string to task (of string)

Comment: Your original code was giving 1000ms for the downloads to complete but with this code, your timer controls how long to wait between requests.  If you really want to hammer the API, with this code, you could bring the timer's interval down to 100ms. As Jimi points out, the API might not let you make concurrent calls so you might hit a wall.

Comment: Use `btc.Result`, `doge.Result` and `bnb.Result` to get string from tasks.

Comment: I can't compile your code as I receive the error I just wrote. The api is not currently using any token so you can refresh it millions time and still giving you data.

Comment: Would you be able to make a summary or fix your code in order to atleast make it compile? Thanks

Comment: [Binance FAQ: API limits](https://www.binance.com/en/support/articles/360004492232-API-Frequently-Asked-Questions-FAQ-): The order limits (currently 10 per second and 100,000 per 24 hours) will be dependent on account.

Comment: Thanks Etienne, well now I m curious and bit scared about that, but.. is that limit also for me that i'm just parsing data without using my account token? Or it will be an IP ban doesn't matter if you got an account with them?

Comment: also using 100ms it will be 600 request weight for minute, so I shouldnt care as I'm much below the limit of 1200