# Convert Binance timestamp into valid datetime

Tags: c#, binance

I dont know how to covert timestamp given by Binance server into valid `DateTime`.

`Binance.API.Csharp.Client.Models.General.ServerInfo` returns
`1615724572987` which after conversion to `DateTime` gives
`1/2/0001 9:52:52 PM`
which obviously is not correct.

I tried to find description about ServerInfo type but there is only GetHtml Function.

Answer (score 5):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48757836/compute-date-out-of-timestamp-from-binance-api-python) you will learn that

> "[In binance API] All time and timestamp related fields are in milliseconds." (unix style)

And from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-can-i-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa) you will learn to convert unix timestamp to `DateTime`.

Then combine this knowledge to create this method:

```
public static DateTime BinanceTimeStampToUtcDateTime(double binanceTimeStamp)
{
    // Binance timestamp is milliseconds past epoch
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
    return epoch.AddMilliseconds(binanceTimeStamp);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimemilliseconds?view=net-5.0#System_DateTimeOffset_FromUnixTimeMilliseconds_System_Int64_

Comment: As note by pinkfloydx33, you can use `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66609223/7444103), for example, in a custom `UnixDateTimeConverter`, deserializing the JSON APIs' results

Comment: Thank You very much for Your answers. Example works, didnt know that this is the format I needed to look for.